# GPU performance during feature extraction (Tesla K80)

Tags: python-3.x, keras, gpu, feature-extraction, tesla

I am using the following code to extract features from about 4000 images divided over 30 classes.

```
 for i, label in enumerate(train_labels):
        cur_path = train_path + "/" + label
        count = 1
        for image_path in glob.glob(cur_path + "/*.jpg"):
            img = image.load_img(image_path, target_size=image_size)
            x = image.img_to_array(img)
            x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
            x = preprocess_input(x)
            feature = model.predict(x)
            flat = feature.flatten()
            features.append(flat)
            labels.append(label)
            print ("[INFO] processed - " + str(count))
        count += 1
    print ("[INFO] completed label - " + label)
```

Although, my entire dataset is much larger and is up to 80,000 images. When looking at my GPU memory this bit of code works in Keras (2.1.2) for the 4000 images but takes almost up all my 5gig video RAM of my Tesla K80. I was wondering if I could improve my performance by changing the batch_size or is the way this code works just to heavy for my GPU and should I rewrite it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean  80,000 images? Could you please make the correction is yes.

Comment: Yes my bad 80,000. But the issues already arises when using 8000 images. I was thinking of I should use the ImageDataGenerator, because changing batch_size is not solving my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions.

1)I'm assuming you're storing your images in Numpy array format. This is very memory intensive. Instead, store it as a normal list. When application demands convert it into numpy array. In my case, it reduced memory consumption by 10 times. If your already storing it as a list then 2 solution might solve your problem.

2)Store the results in chunks and Use a generator when feeding it into another model.

```
chunk_of_features=[]
chunk_of_labels=[]
i=0
for i, label in enumerate(train_labels):
        cur_path = train_path + "/" + label
        count = 1
        for image_path in glob.glob(cur_path + "/*.jpg"):
            i+=1
            img = image.load_img(image_path, target_size=image_size)
            x = image.img_to_array(img)
            x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
            x = preprocess_input(x)
            feature = model.predict(x)
            flat = feature.flatten()
            chunk_of_features.append(flat)
            chunk_of_labels.append(label)
            if i==4000:
                with open('useSomeCountertoPreventNameConflict','wb') as output_file:
                    pickle.dump(chunk_of_features,output_file)
                with open('useSomeCountertoPreventNameConflict','wb') as output_file:
                    pickle.dump(chunk_of_labels,output_file)
                chunk_of_features=[]
                chunk_of_labels=[]
                i=0

            print ("[INFO] processed - " + str(count))
        count += 1
    print ("[INFO] completed label - " + label)
```

Comment: Actually, I was already storing them in a list and finally saving them as array. So you would recommend storing them as list (i.e. Pickle?) and then when needing them load the pickle, transform to array and so on? Am I right to see that your second solution contains the chunking and saving as lit. I have to admit that I am quite new to the field of Python, so mind my stupid questions. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What about solution 2? Will it cause any problem?

Comment: I am trying that now, give me a few minutes!

Comment: Is it possible that everything from: 'cur_path' has got an indentation too much? It runs but really slow and I think the prints are off, probably indentations too. Let me look at it a bit longer. The indentations are probably my mistake as I pasted my code wrong.

Comment: It is running now on normal speed. I have to compare the memory use though, I will report back to you when I know more

Comment: Just a few questions though. This might sound silly but where is the actual chunking happening? When feeding this in my logistic classifier model you suggest I use something like model.fit_generator()?

Comment: Your current model which is predicting features is doing great. But the problem is caused because of the list that we are continuously appending to. So, once we realized we were crossing the memory limit we safely pickle it out and free our list. Thus we are breaking our output into several chunks. But when we want to feed these chunks into some other new model for some other work, we must use a generator or fit_on_batch to make all the chunk feel as one for the model.

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately has the chunking for some reason not reduced my memory errors. I was thinking, is 8000 images (not even thinking about 80,000) not just too much for my setup to handle (Tesla K80, 5gig VRAM)? I am extracting features using the InceptionResNetV3 model. Loading that model already costs me about 1,5 gig of VRAM.

Comment: Would you mind posting the architecture or code of your model?

Comment: I have mainly used this tutorial. Which is probably easier than copying my whole code here: https://gogul09.github.io/software/flower-recognition-deep-learning

Comment: But then adjusted to my own dataset and only using the InceptionResNetV2